# 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operal program or batch file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm not a Windows guy, I have been using Linux since 1999.
I installed FFmpeg on my daughter's Windows 10 laptop.
I installed it according to the instructions, set the PATH in the environment variables, go to use it, and get this error:

> 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operal program or batch file

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the path to the *binary* folder, where is the `ffmpeg.exe` file, for example

```
C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin
```

Be aware that the delimiter between individual paths in Windows is the **semicolon** (`;`), and not the colon (`:`) (as in Linux), for example the content of the `PATH` environment variable may be

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Press **Windows + R** key to open run command, type: **sysdm.cpl** and press **ENTER**. Click the Advanced tab, Environment Variables, in "User variables" add the path where ffmpeg.exe is to the "Path" variable. Caution! only the path not path + file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DOS 8.3 naming convention for the "Program Files" folder in the path -
"C:\Progra~1\FFMPEG\bin"

It would not work on my computer until I did this. Then it suddenly worked after dozens of unsuccessful attempts.

On my computer, I also only included it under the "System" Environment Variables, as I found others noting that that's where it worked for them. Create a separate item for "FFmpeg" using the "New" button under "System", and use the path above.

That's what ended up working on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a viable solution in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXDsMKJyK9c)!

After adding the ffmpeg/bin folder to your user variables, you can run cmd or terminal as an administrator because if you are not a computer admin, it will display this message:

> ffmpeg is not recognized

Running CMD as an admin resolves this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue in Windows 11, turned out the fix was to restart the computer. Apparently that updates the Windows path variables.

Answer (score -1):

A fix could also be to add the path to the system environment variables rather than to the user. This can happen if the admin user you used to change the environment variable is different to your login user.

Comment: Covered in this [existing answer](https://superuser.com/a/1757368/)